# How to run commands via NodeJS child process?

Tags: shell, node.js, process, command-line-interface, command-prompt

I am trying to run commands on Windows via NodeJS child processes:

```
var terminal = require('child_process').spawn('cmd');

terminal.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

terminal.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

terminal.on('exit', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});

setTimeout(function() {
    terminal.stdin.write('echo %PATH%');
}, 2000);
```

When it calls `ti.stdin.write`, it writes it to the `stdin` descriptor, but how do I trigger `cmd` to react at this point? How do I send the "enter" key signal that you do when you are actually typing in command prompt? Currently I get no response from `cmd`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Sending a newline `\n` will exectue the command. `.end()` will exit the shell.

I modified the example to work with bash as I'm on osx.

```
var terminal = require('child_process').spawn('bash');

terminal.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

terminal.on('exit', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Sending stdin to terminal');
    terminal.stdin.write('echo "Hello $USER. Your machine runs since:"\n');
    terminal.stdin.write('uptime\n');
    console.log('Ending terminal session');
    terminal.stdin.end();
}, 1000);
```

The output will be:

```
Sending stdin to terminal
Ending terminal session
stdout: Hello root. Your machine runs since:
stdout: 9:47  up 50 mins, 2 users, load averages: 1.75 1.58 1.42
child process exited with code 0
```

Answer (score 27):

You just have to send line end (\n) with the command:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    terminal.stdin.write('echo %PATH%\n');
}, 2000);
```

Comment: +1 @Raivo Laanemets - this is the actual answer to the op's question. While you do need to at some point call the `stdin.end()` if you want to process multiple read / responses you should just terminate with a newline (`\n` works on windows xp / 7)

Answer (score 6):

You can use child_process exec method.
here is an example:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child;

child = exec('echo %PATH%',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        if(stdout!==''){
            console.log('---------stdout: ---------\n' + stdout);
        }
        if(stderr!==''){
            console.log('---------stderr: ---------\n' + stderr);
        }
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log('---------exec error: ---------\n[' + error+']');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you `stdin.end()` at some point or the child process won't exit.