# Run nodejs command line module to output in nodejs web server?

Tags: node.js, command-line, webserver

With an http server made in nodejs can I have it run another nodejs module like jasmine-node, that normally runs in command line, output to the web?

Trying to run jasmine tests from browser instead of command line, new to nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could have 2 node instances. One the http server and the second instance the command line instance to run jasmine. The http server instance would spawn the command line instance. Then you could register a GET route on the http server such as someexample.com/runtests which would call the tests and wait for the tests to finish and respond with the console output. This is sort of unorthodox, but there wouldn't be a direct way to run command line applications through the browser without modifying their source.

Comment: Thanks, thats a bummer, I was hoping because they were both nodejs one could spawn the other more directly and pipe the output.
Thanks, I'll use your suggestion and found this link on command line interaction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389974/how-to-run-commands-via-nodejs-child-process