# grunt.util.spawn command waiting for response

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, command-prompt

I am trying to run an exe file from the command prompt from within a grunt task.  What I have so far is

```
 var done = this.async();
 var cp = grunt.util.spawn({
            cmd: path.resolve(options.RH)
     }, done );

 cp.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
     grunt.verbose.writeln('stdout: ' + data.toString());
 });
```

(there will be args and more interesting stuff later but for now I just want it to run)

It does run and returns the output, however, exe that is running writes a message and then says "to continue please press enter".

This is as far as I get. It just hangs.  Is there a way, to spawn a child that requires input?

I hope this is enough to go on, if not please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the right way to do it ( reference another post ) but it looks like my question is answered here.
[How to run commands via NodeJS child process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389974/how-to-run-commands-via-nodejs-child-process?rq=1)