# Avoiding wait for newline after running childprocess

Tags: node.js

This command is giving my unit tests trouble. The problem is that the test gets stuck waiting for the child process to receive a newline:

```
var cmd = spawn('ls');
```

So, I send a newline, as advised in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389974/how-to-run-commands-via-nodejs-child-process):

```
   setTimeout(function() {
        cmd.stdin.write('\n');
        console.log('Ending terminal session');
    }, 2000);
```

I get this exception:

```
Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
    at Socket.writeAfterFIN [as write] (net.js:275:12)
```

If I run the command from command line, as soon as I hit the enter key the function returns as expected, but it does not send the newline via stdin without the aforementioned error.

Comment: What are the values for `myscript` and `arg1` and `arg2`?

Comment: String values, two file paths, and myscript is just a path to the ImageMagick executable in this case.

Comment: What kind of interactive input is imagemagick requiring? I would think ordinarily something like image conversion would be a non-interactive task.

Comment: @mscdex The point is that it doesn't matter what the process is. If it's `ls` it still freezes until I manually hit the return key.