# How to execute a shell script with node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, shell, express

I have a simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello john"
```

And I also have a very basic server file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  /*
  Code to execute the shell script
  */
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you [read the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process)? Did you [try googling your question](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+execute+a+shell+script+with+node%3F)?

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389974/how-to-run-commands-via-nodejs-child-process) Will be helpful to